# Show and Hide element (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal but I don't want to show it unless it ends doing all the validation.

**So am I trying to hide it in the beginning and show it if it passes through the validation process..**

My code still shows the modal when I click the btnSubmit

```js
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#creationModal').modal('hide');
  //if the flow is not validated
  var flowName = $('#flowName').val();
  //check if it exists
  validateFlowName(flowName);
});

function validateFlowName(flowName) {

  if //some validation processes) 

  {

  } 
//if passes all validations, show it
  else {

    $('#creationModal').modal('show');

  }
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" data-target="#creationModal" data-toggle="modal" id="btnSubmit"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When page is load, at that time `$('#creationModal').hide()` will hide your element and then you will click on button `$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e)` will call. In this function you can check the condition like this :

```
$('#creationModal').hide();

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //if the flow is not validated
  var flowName = $('#flowName').val();
  //check if it exists
  if(flowName) {
    $('#creationModal').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#creationModal').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the data-target="#creationModal" data-toggle="modal" from your button :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" id="btnSubmit"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-target="#creationModal" data-toggle="modal"` line of code from your button, because this line will open modal. Above line is required if you want open modal directly.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" id="btnSubmit"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create</button>
```